# Pandas Dataframe Left Merge turning into Inner Merge because of where condition

Tags: pandas, merge, where-clause

I have 2 dataframes that I need to do a left merge on (don't want to lose the records from the first df).  I can do the merge fine, but when I add a where condition (I want records where time_dim_id is between call_dim_id and evt_dim_id), I lose the records that have nulls in evt_dim_id (I want to retain these as well). 
This is the beginning of my code for the where condition.  How do I add an "OR" so I keep the records where the evt_dim_id is null?

```
df_MG_where = df_MG[((df_MG.time_dim_id >= df_MG.call_dim_id) & (df_MG.time_dim_id <= df_MG.evt_dim_id)) | (df_MG.evt_dim_id ????)]
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can add function [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) to condition:

```
print df_MG
   time_dim_id  call_dim_id  evt_dim_id
0           10            3        25.0
1            8            4         NaN
2            1            5         2.3
3            1            6         2.4
4            2            7         1.2
5            2            8         5.5
6            2            9         5.7

df_MG_where = df_MG[(((df_MG.time_dim_id >= df_MG.call_dim_id) & 
                    (df_MG.time_dim_id <= df_MG.evt_dim_id)) | (df_MG.evt_dim_id.isnull() ))]

print df_MG_where                    
   time_dim_id  call_dim_id  evt_dim_id
0           10            3          25
1            8            4         NaN
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was the last piece of the puzzle.  Really appreciate the help.